# Why do I have two notifications when I get emails from gmail?

Tags: gmail, htc-one, stock-email-app, htc-one-mini

I don't understand why I get two notifications on my phone every time I get an email. Is my phone running emails from two different apps? It's HTC One Mini, running Android 4.4.2.

[image: Screenshot]
<sup>Screenshot (click for larger variant)</sup>

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are running two email applications.

From your screenshot the one with the big "N" is the `Gmail appliction` the other is from the HTC Email application, called email.

You can remove your account from either, or disable the whole application if that suits better.

**To [remove the account](http://smallbusiness.chron.com/remove-htc-mail-account-android-35450.html) from HTC Email.**

1. Press the "Application Menu" button at the bottom of your HTC device's screen.
2. Scroll to the "Email" icon, then tap it once to launch the program. If the application opens to the inbox of one of your accounts, press the "Back" button at the bottom of the phone to return to the "Accounts" menu.
3. Touch and hold your finger on the account that you want to delete until a pop-up window opens on the screen.
4. Touch the "Remove Account" option.
5. Tap the "OK" button to remove the account.

**Alternatively** (since this doesn't seem to work on this device in particular):

1. Go to Settings
2. Click Applications
3. Click `Mail`
4. Click `Clear Data`

As another alternative if the mail application is 'mail' rather than 'email' there is a `remove account` option in the settings.

---

**To remove a Google account**

Go to `Settings > Accounts and sync > Your Google Account Name`

You can either untick Gmail in the synch settings, OR click the button `Remove Account` to completely remove your Google account (which you may not want to do for obvious reasons).

Comment: There is only an icon called "Mail", but when I open it and press back, it only takes me to the Application menu. And when I press and hold the icon, it just tries to add it to my home screen, not remove the account.

Comment: O...k... I have it here, that's a bit weird. Is there ANY settings in the Mail app? You could go to `Settings > Applications > Mail > Clear Data` and that may do it also? I've updated the answer.

Comment: Ah yeah, I was able to delete the account through Settings. Cheers.

Comment: @LeoKing that's great, if this helps please consider accepting it and/or upvoting as it may help others. I'll add more on the settings now.

Comment: I know how SE works, I'm just sending myself an email to make sure it doesn't give me double notifications :).

Comment: Cool! Just habit sometimes to be honest, was lazy and didn't check your account. HOPEFULLY it actually works now! :)

Comment: Well pewp, so far I'm not receiving a single thing :P. I don't know how long it takes for a notification to arrive. When it does and it's working, I'll accept the answer :).

Comment: Hmm, makes sure that your Gmail account is set to synch in the settings under your Google account!

Comment: Interesting, I only got the email notifications when I opened up gmail. In any case, only one notf. Thanks!

Comment: Aw damn. Now I'm getting two notifications again.

Comment: @LeoKing is there some HTC specific synch setting somewhere maybe? You could try deleting the mail data, and disabling the app?